# Showing the expectation of the record of iid random variables is infinity

Tags: probability

Take a sequence of iid RVs: $(X_n, n \geq 1)$. I want to show $E[\inf\{n>1:X_n>X_1\}]=\infty$. I know how this would work for geometric processes, but this statement seems to be more general. Also, I think there could be a  way to write it as a markov process like the famous Gambler's ruin problem. But, I want a simpler solution.

I think I should use the fact that ($N = \inf\{n>1:X_n>X_1\}$) $E[N] = \sum_{n\geq1}P(N \geq n)$ , but I'm stuck and don't know how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional on $X_1=x,$ the expected value of $N$ is $$E(N\mid X_1=x) = 1 + \frac{1}{P(X>x)} $$ since we are simply waiting for an event with probability $P(X>x)$ to happen. Thus, law of total expectation gives $$ E(N) - 1  = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f_X(x)}{P(X>x)}dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f_X(x)}{1-F_X(x)}dx = \int_0^1\frac{1}{1-F}dF = \infty$$ where $f_X$ is the PDF of $X,$ $F_X$ is the CDF, and we used the variable trasformation $F = F_X(x)$ in the second to last equality.

(On a side note I don't think this result actually requires the PDF to exist, or any assumptions about $X$ at all. So, consider the approach I took as a heuristic stand-in for something more rigorous that I don't know/remember the details of :))

---

**Edit** Now that I think about it, the approach you're starting with works. We have $$P(N\ge n+1)= P(X_n,X_{n-1},\ldots, X_2 \le X_1) $$ and by symmetry, $P(X_n,X_{n-1},\ldots, X_2 \le X_1) \ge 1/n,$ so  $\sum_n P(N\ge n)= \infty.$